# Re-downloading images with different sizes when using Kingfisher

Tags: swift, caching, kingfisher

i have an app that works with API JSON response. Just retrieving a simple array of items. Each item has an url with a high-res image. I'm using Kingfisher to get this images and resize to my ImageView size (that placed on my MainView)

```
//MainViewController
itemImageMainVC.kf.setImage(
    with: URL(string: itemModel.artImage),
    options: [
        .processor(DownsamplingImageProcessor(size: itemImageMainVC.bounds.size) >> RoundCornerImageProcessor(cornerRadius: 16, targetSize: itemImageMainVC.bounds.size)),
        .scaleFactor(UIScreen.main.scale),
        .transition(.fade(0.2)),
        .cacheOriginalImage
    ])
```

Everything is fine here, i've got my images on my MainView inside TableView, and they cached well. BUT! If i try to open and display the same images, but with different sizes on the SecondView, i see the same transition animation on the SecondView, so i guess that they started to download again when they shouldn't.

```
//SecondViewController
itemImageSecondVC.kf.setImage(
    with: URL(string: itemModel.artImage),
    options: [
        .processor(DownsamplingImageProcessor(size: itemImageSecondVC.bounds.size) >> RoundCornerImageProcessor(cornerRadius: 16, targetSize: itemImageSecondVC.bounds.size)),
        .scaleFactor(UIScreen.main.scale),
        .transition(.fade(0.2)),
        .cacheOriginalImage
    ])
```

itemImageMainVC and itemImageSecondVC have different sizes.

What i'm doing wrong? I just want to download/display images on the MainView and instantly show them when i open SecondView, without re-downloading

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to use the cacheKey, it should be the last path component (or event the absoluteUrlString) from your image url or something that is unique.

```
let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: url, cacheKey: url.lastPathComponent)
self.imageView.kf.setImage(with: resource, placeholder: UIImage(named: "placeholder-image"), options: nil, progressBlock: nil) { (result) in
    switch result {
    case .success(_):
        // Success case
    case .failure(_):
        // Failed case
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem was with the RoundCorner processor. Since i request an image with different size